# VBA excel module works not always

Tags: excel, vba

Hello stackoverflow users,

I am facing the following problem, I receive a very big Excel table every day and would like to simplify it. So I decided to automatize this task, I wrote a VBA script and saved it as a module.

I open and execute it, sometimes it works. I am searching for hours already for any hint.

```
Function HideRows()
    ActiveSheet.Rows("2:2").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("5:5").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("8:8").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("10:10").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("11:11").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("24:24").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("29:29").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("30:30").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("31:31").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ActiveSheet.Rows("37:37").EntireRow.Hidden = True
End Function


Function HideColumns()      
    Dim rng As Range

    For Each rng In Range("C:J").Columns
        rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Next rng

    For Each rng In Range("L:M").Columns
        rng.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Next rng
End Function
Function FilterByAttributes()
    beginRow = 1
    EndRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row
    ActiveSheet.Range("K" & EndRow).AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=RGB(255, 0, 0), Operator:=xlFilterCellColor
End Function


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Call HideColumns
    Call HideRows
    Call FilterByAttributes
End Sub
```

Is there any better possibility to format the table with less amount of clicks according to the conditions in my script?

UPDATE: the algorithm of my actions:

1. Download excel table from my email
2. Open this excel table
3. Open "Developer tools tab"->Visual Basic-> File-> Import->Select module->Execute Module. This step has to be somehow simplified, have no ideas how
4. Continue working with the resultant table

I would like to make as less clicks as possible for the "special filter"

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need a loop to hide those columns: `ActiveSheet.Columns("C:J").Hidden = True`, and similarly for `L:M`.

Comment: Your use of ActiveSheet might be the cause of the module sometimes not working as intended (i.e. being performed on a different sheet). Make sure that the downloaded Excel file is open and the correct sheet is selected when executing this procedure. Maybe also consider copying this code to the workbook you want to use it on.

Comment: What exactly works sometimes (but not always). How does it deviate from what you expect. Have you tried to single step through the code and check that everything happens as you have planned?

Comment: Consider adding the macro to a [personal workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566) instead of importing it every day to a new excel file.

Comment: @TomBrunberg Sometimes my script hides only columns, rows are not going to be hidden and filter doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some thoughts:

1) Consider [adding the macro to a personal workbook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/copy-your-macros-to-a-personal-macro-workbook-aa439b90-f836-4381-97f0-6e4c3f5ee566) instead of importing it every day to a new excel file.

2) You don't need a loop to hide columns: `ActiveSheet.Columns("C:J").Hidden = True`, and similarly for `.Columns("L:M")`.

3) The `Call` keyword can be dropped.

4) Add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all variables, specifically `beginRow` and `EndRow`.